# Preg_match multiple instances reuse delimiter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've revised the question as I did not explain correctly the first time.

Can someone please help me with this regex. I can't seem to figure out how to use the same delimeter as the end of one match and then reuse as the start of the next.

In the following code I'm trying to match everything in between each delimiter_test statement.

```
$string = "

delimiter_test this is a test
this is more data,etc
delimiter_test this is another test
and this is more data
delimiter_test this yet another test
and this is even more data

";
```

Here is the regex I've tried:

```
preg_match_all('/delimiter_test(.*?)delimiter_test/s', $string, $matches);
```

And here are my results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => delimiter_test this is a test
this is more data,etc
delimiter_test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  this is a test
this is more data,etc

        )

)
```

So it only gets what is between the first and second 'delimiter_test'.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks, Max

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to get it to recognize line feeds, but in my string, there could be multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer:

You can use [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=delimiter_test).*?(?=delimiter_test|$)/s', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/171224)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for what I wrote above, but I need something different, I really need to match between each set of delimter_test.

Comment: Can you update the question to refrain exactly what you want to match then?

Comment: @user3792399 Great. If you dont mind clicking the checkmark next to the answer to accept it if this worked for you